# laravel Job on queue stuck when WithoutOverlapping middleware is present

Tags: laravel

i have a scheduled job with spawns a long running job every 3 minutes, so i tried adding a without overlapping middleware to prevent 2 same job running. it works for a few days but now it got stucked. it seems like the cached key is not being expired.

cache is set to DB. i tried running `php artisan cache:clear` or truncating `cache` table not works.

i have supervisor to check if queue is running using this command

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=high,default --tries=3 --backoff=10 --timeout=0
```

```php
public function middleware(): array
{
    $key = "sync-{$this->provider_id}-{$this->user_id}";

    return [(new WithoutOverlapping($key))->releaseAfter(60)->expireAfter(60 * 10)];
}
```